# regex getting url's embedded in html tags

Tags: c#, regex

I have searched with no luck on google, I'm trying to extract links in this format:

```
<cite class=Rm>https://www.example.com/<b>index</b>.<b>php</b>?<b>username</b>=laura</cite>
```

this would be the result: `https://www.example.com/index.php?username=laura`

Comment: What are you attempting to parse?

Comment: For all questions where both HTML and regex are used, [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) should be posted...

Comment: The `HtmlAgilityPack` is your friend with this @sgroves855.

Comment: Greg that would be an option, but then i'd need to rewrite a ton of code

Comment: I fully agree with the previous comments. Do not parse html with regex. That being said, in your case it seems like you can just remove all substings that match `\<[^>]+\>` to aquire the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to pair opening and closing tags you could just strip the tags.

```
string input = "<cite class=Rm>https://www.example.com/<b>index</b>.<b>php</b>?<b>username</b>=laura</cite>";
string pattern = "<[^>]*>";
string replacement = "";
string result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(input, pattern, replacement);
```

Otherwise you will need to use [balancing groups](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah(v=vs.110).aspx#balancing_group_definition). I don't know how to do it on a single step but you could try this:

```
    string input = "<cite class=Rm>https://www.example.com/<b>index</b>.<b>php</b>?<b>username</b>=laura</cite>";
    string pattern = "(?'open'<(?'tag'[^ ]*)[^>]*>)(?'middle'.*?)(?'close-open'</\\k'tag'>)";
    string replacement = "${middle}";
    string step1 = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(input, pattern, replacement);
    string result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(step1, pattern, replacement);
```

Answer (score -1):

In the future, more examples and the consistency of syntax are hugely helpful.

This regex assumes that each line you're trying to capture follows this format (asterisk is, of course, a wildcard).

```
<cite class=Rm>*<b>*</b>.<b>*</b>?<b>*</b>=*</cite>
```

Here is the regex

```
<cite class=Rm>(.*?)<b>(.*?)<\/b>\.<b>(.*?)<\/b>\?<b>(.*?)</b>=(.*?)</cite>
```

And the matching pattern is something like (Sorry, I can't help you much with C#)

```
$1$2.$3?$4=$5
```

Complex html matching, as the comments point out, is a house built on sand. It is better to use a parser for more-complex matching because then things like order of attributes, existence of elements, etc, only matter when you need them to matter.

While this is not a complex match, I hope you'll keep that in mind in future endeavors.